# Python - OpenCV, PIL - how to display dataframe with images in columns

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I would like to print/display dataframe, BUT want an image before each row.

So I have a dataframe with 'img' column as an array for an image. I've also tried to accomplish this (and succeeded) buy turning to HTML, however, I can't use the HTML file for what I would like to do after. All I want to do is display the dataframe in a window. (I've been reading about tkinter as a possibility??)

I was displaying this (without the images) using as strings, and it turned out perfect, but now I want to add the logos, which obviosly are not text, so I can't use PIL draw.text().

My first step was to simply display a filtered dataframe which I did by puting the text into a blank canvas in cvopen. So here's the string I get with using tabulate() and draw.text() to display as an image. What I had originally (without images):

```
Player                Position      Count
--------------------  ----------  -------
Marshawn Lynch        RB          19
Michael Crabtree      WR          19
Amari Cooper          WR          7
```

So now, I want to add the team logo in front of the player names.
Here's the dataframe I was able to get, where 'img' column is the array of the images:

```
img             Nickname                Position    Count
"[[[255 ...     Marshawn Lynch          RB          19
"[[[255 ...     Michael Crabtree        WR          19
"[[[255 ...     Amari Cooper            WR          7
```

And I want to display it as I was able to get below, or something similar. This is the results I would like to get but NOT as an html file.

[image]

So the question is, how can I achieve the above table, but not as an HTML file?